# Terminal, svn copy not working after multiple svn commands

Tags: macos, svn, command-line, terminal, svn-copy

I recently executed a command similar to the following:

```
svn copy https://myRepo.com/projectFolder1/myProject.prj https://myRepo.com/projectFolder2 -m "copied myProject.prj to projectFolder2"&& svn update
```

and indeed the copy went through then the update too.

But every other command similar to that afterwards to copy more projects is presenting me with this symbol: ">" which i assume means I need to/ want to enter more stuff? and the actual command is not being executed.

Second command:

```
svn copy https://myRepo.com/projectFolder1/myProject2.prj https://myRepo.com/projectFolder2 -m "copied myProject2.prj to projectFolder2"&& svn update
```

I know to exit that I have to hit: cntl c. But my intent is to execute the copy commands. I could not find a solution to this (possibly because i don't know what to search for exactly). Am I doing something wrong or missing something here? Thank you

Comment: Show us one of the other commands you're typing in that isn't working exactly as you have it on the screen.

Comment: @CDahn I've added the second command

Comment: I have successfully done this before without using the && and instead entering each update command after the copy. All worked well until today that I decided to combine the update with the copy

Comment: okay, i have found the issue, in textEdit, when I enter && after the quotes that close off the commit message, the quotes get changed from " to “. This is not happening in TextWrangler as a test, just in TextEdit. Not using TextEdit again! Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do executing multiple commands. Instead the issue is in TextEdit.app. Entering && after these quotes:" will result in your quotes changing to smart quotes which are “.
So entering && after:

> "

will result in

> “&&

where the quotes are different if you look closely.

As a test, TextWrangler.app does not do this, just TextEdit.app, so it maybe a bug.

I am henceforth using TextWrangler to prepare my Terminal commands.